# How can I disable/remove authorize button in swagger drf_yasg (maintain CSRF) - django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, csrf, drf-yasg

How to disable the Authorize button in drf_yasg ? (I still want CSRF to work)

[image]

UPDATE:
currently, I have the settings this way, because I would like to remove Django login and also maintain csrf. However, Authorize button still exist (How do I remove the authorize button and also maintain csrf)

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,

    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'Basic': {
            'type': 'basic'
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75332879/how-can-i-disable-remove-authorize-button-in-swagger-drf-spectacular-django Any idea about this ??

Answer (score 2):

You can set the [**`SECURITY_DEFINITIONS`**--(doc)](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/settings.html#security-definitions-settings) to `None` or set it as per the OpenAPI schema definition,

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': None
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, CSRF is completely gone. I'ved updated the question a bit. I would like to remove Django admin and maintain csrf. But I dont want also the Authorize button. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line in options:

```
.addBearerAuth()
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, by using `SUPPORTED_SUBMIT_METHODS`in `SWAGGER_SETTINGS`
make it like `SUPPORTED_SUBMIT_METHODS': [],`