# How can I disable/remove authorize button in swagger drf_spectacular - django

Tags: python-3.x, django, drf-spectacular

I'm working on DRF-spectacular.
My question is how to disable Authorize Button in DRF-spectacular.

Are there any settings?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QJ2T.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this value in your REST Framework, this is in settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': []
}
```